# Silverlight not working

Tags: windows, silverlight

For some reason my system is failing to identify that there is an instance of silverlight already installed on my system and I am not sure why it is behaving this way.

I have been using silverlight for a good amount of time on this system and now suddenly when I browse to some sites, it says that i need to install silverlight. I a not sure how silverlight was uninstalled from my system. Surprisingly enough, I can run Netflix on my system, which tells me that silverLight is doing Ok on my system.

On the other hand when I try to install silverlight on my system, it tells me that another copy is being installed on the system. It shows me same message again and again even though I restart my PC. Any way to deal with this?

Comment: When I go to control panel and try uninstalling it, it says the same thing that another program is being installed, please try again later.

Answer (score 2):

Possible issue may be that the silverlight plugin is disabled.

For example in chrome type 'chrome://plugins' into address bar and you should see silverlight disabled - simply click 'Enable' and all should be well.